# GitHub search a path in a repository via the GitHub CLI

Tags: github-cli

I have this search via the code browser:

- [repo:RapidCircle/vscode path:.vscode/](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ARapidCircle%2Fvscode%20path%3A.vscode%2F&type=code)

It searches for a path inside a repository and it does returns results.

No matter how I try it to translate it to GitHub CLI I can not succeed. The following one (Windows):

```
gh api --method=GET "search/code?q=repo:RapidCircle/vscode+path:.vscode/"
```

returns empty.

So does the following one (Ubuntu) too:

```
gh api -X GET search/code -f 'q=repo:RapidCircle/vscode+path:.vscode/'
```

Did some extra investigation and these queries do not return result either:

```
gh api -X GET search/code -f q='repo:RapidCircle/vscode' -F per_page=100
```

```
gh api --method=GET "search/code?q=repo:RapidCircle/vscode"
```

But the repo ([RapidCircle/vscode](https://github.com/RapidCircle/vscode)) seems there. Ok. Fine. It might not be indexed ([Search for the repo in an other way](https://github.com/search?q=RapidCircle%2Fvscode&type=repositories)).

Let us look at another repo. This Github CLI does returns values:

```
gh api -X GET search/code -f q='repo:cli/cli' -F per_page=100
```

If I try to add a path variable ([works via web](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acli%2Fcli%20path%3A%2F%5Einternal%5C%2F%2F%20&type=code)) but not with GitHub CLI:

```
gh api -X GET search/code -f q='repo:cli/cli+path:/^internal\//' -F per_page=100
```

Same but Windows:

```
gh api --method=GET "search/code?q=repo:cli/cli+path:/^internal\//"
```

What is wrong?

A more general question would be:

- Is there a tool out there that could translate GitHub Web searches to CLI commands?

I am guessing there is limitation on what you can do with GitHub CLI API vs real WebSearch (on the site).

Submitted the issue here too: [GitHub CLI Issues/Discussions](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/68413)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered my question regarding why the first query did not work and that was because this repository: [RapidCircle/vscode](https://github.com/RapidCircle/vscode) is a fork of [microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode).

So you need the "+fork:true" to the CLI to be able to search.

Windows full command:

```
gh api --method=GET "search/code?q=repo:RapidCircle/vscode+path:.vscode/+fork:true"
```

And here is a syntax that worked for me in Linux (Ubuntu):

```
gh api -X GET search/code -f 'q=repo:RapidCircle/vscode path:.vscode/ fork:true'
```

Please pay attention that instead of "+" there is space there.

As for these commands:

Ubuntu:

```
gh api -X GET search/code -f q='repo:cli/cli+path:/^internal\//' -F per_page=100
gh api -X GET search/code -f q='repo:cli/cli path:/^internal\//' -F per_page=100
```

Windows:

```
gh api --method=GET "search/code?q=repo:cli/cli+path:/^internal\//"
```

They are not working because this search pattern: /^internal// is Regexp (regex) and it seams GitHub CLI does not know that one yet.

Commands like these (regexp (regex) free) work:

Ubuntu:

```
gh api -X GET search/code -f q='repo:cli/cli path:internal/' -F per_page=100
```

Windows:

```
gh api --method=GET "search/code?q=repo:cli/cli+path:internal/"
```